# Latex: words don't align inside big bracket

Tags: math-mode, equations

This is the code I used:

```
$\textbf{Z}=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & \textrm{\textrm{if values are not inflated }}\\
1 & \textrm{if values are inflated }
\end{array}\right.$ }
```

and this result pops up:
[image]

as you may see, the 'if' on the second line is not in line with the 'if' in the first line. Can anyone please advise me on what to do? Thank you:)

Comment: Recheck the code you provided. It does not match your picture.

Comment: Why do you have two `\textrm` commands in the first case?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The code you posted [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWWIM.png) for me. You probably have something else that is causing this. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. *Off-topic*: you probably don't need the nested `\textrm{\textrm{if }}`.

Comment: sorry! I put in the wrong code. The code that I first put does work but the code I just put in now (which has more words) gives me a bit of a problem. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Clarke `\begin{array}{cc}` creates two `c`entered columns. You probably want the second column `l`eft-aligned: `\begin{array}{cl}`. Or even better, use the `cases` environment of `amsmath` as Christoph90 showed in his answer, the spacing will be much better.

Answer (score 7):

For a simpler typing, I suggest loading `mathtools`, which extends `amsmath`,  and use it `cases*` (with a star) environment: the second column is in text mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    $ \mathbf{Z}= \begin{cases*}
        0 & if values are not inflated \\
        1 & if values are inflated
    \end{cases*} $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry for the now fixed typo, and thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 6):

You can fix your code by specifying the second column of the `align` environment as left-aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbf{Z}= \left\lbrace\begin{array}{cl} 
    0 & \textrm{if values are not inflated}\\
    1 & \textrm{if values are inflated}
    \end{array} \right.$
\end{document}
```

However, I'd suggest you do these things using the `cases` environment from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbf{Z}= \begin{cases}
        0 & \textrm{if values are not inflated}\\
        1 & \textrm{if values are inflated}
    \end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all the comments! They were all really helpful and I managed to fix it!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) cases instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
  \begin{cases}
  0 & \textrm{if values are not inflated}\\
  1 & \textrm{if values are inflated}
  \end{cases}
$
\end{document}
```